# Cordova ios App: how to open app when xml link are clicked in Safari

Tags: ios, cordova

With Android, the application opens when links xml, rss or atom are selected in Safari.

To do this, I use the Cordovan-webintent plugin, and I add following case in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/xml" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And I get the file in the application with the Cordovan-webintent plugin

I can not find a solution to do the same with IOS, ie open a file with the app when the "mine type" is met.

URL scheme does not seem to fit the need.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Comment: If above doesnt work, try this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578951/file-associating-on-ios-opening-a-plain-text-file-from-safari

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how to get the file in cordova app?

Comment: Thank you very much Aslam! it makes the job.